# How to handle mat-checkbox checked and unchecked event

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular14

Trying to get the value of checked and unchecked checkbox values when clicking on the every checkbox. How to do it? How to handle the mat-checkbox events? If anyone knows please help to find the solutions.

```
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let data of filteredData | async"
    [value]="data"
    [disabled]="isDisable(data)"
  >
    <div (click)="optionClicked($event, data)">
      <mat-checkbox
        [checked]="data.selected"
        (change)="toggleSelection(data)"
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
        [disabled]="isDisable(data)"
      >
        {{ data.item }}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </div>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ebuzba?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fmauto%2Fmauto.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

> Example

```
 <mat-checkbox
    [checked]="data.selected"
    (change)="toggleSelection($event, data)"
    [disabled]="isDisable(data)">
      {{ data.item }}
  </mat-checkbox>


import { MatCheckboxChange } from '@angular/material/checkbox'

toggleSelection(checkbox: MatCheckboxChange, data: YourDataType) {

  // Where checkbox value would be something like
  // { source: MatCheckbox, checked: true }

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    // Do stuff;
  }
}
```

NOTE: If you want to update the checkbox value programmatically, you should use either [(ngModel)] or Angular Reactive FormControl

Comment: New SO 73623913